# Run ssh commands across all gce instances

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a bunch of GCE instances and I want to run the same shell command on all of them. Is it possible to do something like `gcloud compute ssh --command="ls -al" my-instance1 my-instance2 my-instance3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gcloud compute instances list --format='value[separator=","](name,zone)'` to get a list like:

```
my-instance1,my-zone1
my-instance2,my-zone2
my-instance3,my-zone3
```

Then you can use bash [Substring Removal](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to extract the parts before and after the comma.

```
var="before,after"
before="${var%,*}"
after="${var#*,}"
```

Put it all in a loop and add trailing '&' to run things in the background:

```
for instance in $(gcloud compute instances list --format='value[separator=","](name,zone)'); do
  name="${instance%,*}";
  zone="${instance#*,}";
  gcloud compute ssh $name --zone=$zone --command="ls -al" &
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44446346/4190565), here is how to do the same without Substring Removal:

```
for i z in $(gcloud compute instances list --format='value(name, zone)'); do 
  gcloud compute ssh $i --command="ls -lah" --zone=$z; 
done
```